# VIM Color Scheme issue(s)

Tags: vim, color

My Problem is that I am having trouble installing and using a new color scheme for VIM 7.2.

Here's what I'm doing to install the new color scheme:

1. I navigate to the terminal on my local machine:  Ubuntu 10.04 > Main Menu > Applications > Accessories > Terminal
2. I then SSH into a development machine.
3. Next I download (for example) wombat.vim from here:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1778
4. Then I move wombat.vim to ~/.vim/colors
5. Finally I add the following to my .vimrc file:

   ```
   set t_Co=256
   set background=dark
   colors wombat
   ```

Here's what it should look like: http://dengmao.wordpress.com/2007/01/22/vim-color-scheme-wombat/ [link for screenshots found on vim.org]

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:  http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/ON6SOx5pXtXd_OsEUkW7mL_t_I-kAslfDzoIG27VNGs?feat=directlink

Any help is much appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

> $ tput colors
> 256
> $ echo $TERM
> xterm-256color

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal is probably using 88 colors, or you do not have the `$TERM` variable set correctly. From within your terminal use `tput colors` to see if you have an 88 or 256 color terminal. If it reports 256, your `$TERM` variable is probably not set correctly -- try changing it to `xterm-256color` in your `.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: The $TERM variable is set correctly as well as the terminal being set to xterm-256color.

Comment: `TERM` is set correctly on both the local and development machines? Do you have anything odd in .Xdefaults on either machine (e.g. *.color1: #abcdef) that might change your colors? If you can, grab the output of `256colors.pl` (google) and screenshot it as well.

Comment: Bottom answer is correct but I'll leave this up in case it helps others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

That colorscheme is GUI-only.  For it to work in the terminal, you'll need a plugin like godlygeek's CSApprox and a GUI-aware vim.